# OSX Cocoa Core-Bluetooth delegate and UI update thread safety

Tags: macos, cocoa, thread-safety, core-bluetooth, cocoa-bindings

I have the OSX BLE heartrate example from: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/HeartRateMonitor/Introduction/Intro.html. This example updates the heartrate via binding the NSTextField to the `heartRate` property. `heartRate` is updated in `peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic`, which updates the bound NSTextView accordingly.  Isn't `peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` on another thread, but this works fine since the control's update is handled 'behind the scenes' by Cocoa?

I added another NSTextView to which I created an outlet ivar. This ivar also gets updated in `peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` and `[txtfldHR setIntegerValue:bpm];` is called. This also seems to work properly. But isn't updating the NSTextField via the IBOutlet dangerous (or shouldn't work at all) from another thread? How can I updated the NSTextField via the function call safely without using bindings?

I've made a similar app in Android and there I need to pass the heartrate value via a message from the BLE callback to the UI thread in order to update the UI controls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the sample code you will see that the `CBCentralManager` is initialised using the following code -

```
manager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
```

If you refer to the documentation for the `queue` parameter of `initWithDelegate`, it says -

> The dispatch queue to use to dispatch the central role events. If the
>   value is nil, the central manager dispatches central role events using
>   the main queue.

This means that your various Bluetooth delegate events will be executed using the main queue.

If you were using a different queue for your delegate operations then you would need to explicitly dispatch UI update events on the main queue via something like `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() ^{  //code });`

Comment: If a different queue were used for delegate operations, would the bound NSTextField still operate as it currently does? When would one use a different queue?

Comment: That, I don't know as I am not an OS X programmer and iOS doesn't have bindings.  Sorry.

Comment: Is it okay to use the main queue if my app receives notifications at  (~8kBps), or will I risk blocking the UI (from user inputs)?

Comment: You need to try it, but assuming 20 byte BLE packets that is about 400 packets per second or one packet every 0.0025 seconds.  On a CPU that can execute millions of instructions per second I doubt that it will have much impact.